# Tableviewcells disappear when search bar is tapped - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I implemented a search feature in my tableview application. The only issue is when I tap the search bar, then tap cancel, cells that were previously shown have disappeared. This is all stock; nothing has changed. When I added the search display controller I added it from storyboard with no configuration.

[Before Search is tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds94y.png)

```
import UIKit

class DataTableExercisesTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

let exercises = ["Abs", "Arms", "Back", "Chest", "Legs", "Shoulders", "Triceps"]
var filteredTableData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar


        return controller
    })()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if resultSearchController.active {
        return filteredTableData.count
    } else {
        return exercises.count
    }
}





override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ExerciseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)



    // Configure the cell...

    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = exercises[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}


 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

self.tableView.reloadData()


}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (exercises as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

[After Search is tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdGRo.png)

Comment: You have a bug in your code somewhere. Post the code that shows/hides the search bar as well as the code that filters your data.

Comment: @DuncanC That's the thing. No code has been set up. I just added it to my tableview from the objects library in storyboard. Do you recommend any resources to learn how to set it up?

Comment: http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/ Follow this link

Comment: There must be bug in your code. Please post your code.

Comment: @DuncanC Here I updated the question with my code.

Comment: @Evana Updated with code.

Comment: Try to debug your code line by line and find out how many cell return when the cell disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to implement the UISearchControllerDelegate method: didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)

This is called when your search controller is dismissed. Here you can reload your tableView data.

you can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontrollerdelegate

Answer (score 0):

I have just change the resultSearchController's initialization like below, and then it work.

```
self.resultSearchController = ({
    let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

    return controller
})()
```

```